# PDFLatex CheckBox symbol does not show correctly in PDF viewer (Preview on Apple)

Tags: pdftex

I want to customise the CheckBox appearance for an active PDF i need to create. Checkboxes should look like the "MS Word" type of checkbox, so displaying a cross when checked. I employ the "Checkboxsymbol" parameter when creating the file:

\CheckBox[width=0.7em, height=0.7em, checkboxsymbol=\ding{56}]{ System test case}

But when i open the produced PDF and check the unchecked box, the "default" symbol appears: 
[image]

In addition, because i want to have this particular page in LANDSCAPE, the sign shows in the wrong orientation.

I use "Preview" on a Mac computer. This is where the problem appears. All works fine when i use Acrobat DC instead. Nevertheless - is it a "viewer only" problem ? How can i make sure that the wrong char does not appear on any browser (i develop and do not have full control on my users environment. I want similar behaviour on all platforms & viewers. This is why i choose PDF in the first place....)

Thanks !

Comment: Well, it is most likely not a rotation problem here. Since i want to use "Cross" as check indicator and this works on Acrobat, i have no way to tell whether we have a rotation here (i guess we have but it makes no difference with the cross :-)). The core problem is that Preview on Apple uses not the cross but the default check sign is is supposed NOT to show.

Comment: Support of interactive elements like forms, OCG layers, Javascript, etc. is very much viewer dependent, if you want uniform user experience across platforms and viewers then it is best to avoid such things.